# How to obtain OAuth 2 access token from Viva Wallet

Tags: php, curl, oauth

In this step I need send this parameters:

```
 POST https://demo-accounts.vivapayments.com/connect/token HTTP/1.1
 Authorization: Basic Z2VuZXJpY19hY3F1aXJpbmdfY2xpZW50LmFwcHMudml2YXBheW1lbnRzLmNvbTpnZW5lcmljX2FjcXVpcmluZ19jbGllbnQ
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 grant_type=client_credentials
```

#### What I done : (ACCESS_TOKEN I already gets)

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://demo-accounts.vivapayments.com/connect/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => ACCESS_TOKEN,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

#### The error I received:

Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reference #7.85c5d3ba.1606074405.4bd39133

#### Link that of API : ( I stoped in Step 2: Request access token )

https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/authentication/#oauth-2-token-generation

Comment: You should send your token with prefix: `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`

Comment: hello Vladimir, Tnks a lot for the answer.. I put like this: "Bearer ". ACCESS_TOKEN, but not worked! : (   .. I dont know what I do, because I so late in my project

Comment: There is no such thing as "doesn't work". Please provide the exact result or error.

Comment: so, it returns the same error :
 Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reference #7.85c5d3ba.1606080025.4c2e3140

Comment: Why are you trying to send a request to `https://demo-accounts.vivapayments.com/connect/token`? Did you say you already have a token?

Comment: good question, I thing is the way they implement the API, as you can see in second steps in this link :  https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/authentication/#oauth-2-token-generation

Comment: I understand what is written there but don't understand what you are trying to do. When I understand that then maybe I can help. Are you trying to get the token? Or you are trying to use the token after you obtained it? What is inside `ACCESS_TOKEN`? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Vladimir Serykh, 
I need to generate my token. inside the variable ACCESS_TOKEN I put the [Client ID]: [Client Secret] in Base64 format, maybe I was unhappy in the name of the variable ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Yes, `ACCESS_TOKEN` is misleading. It should be `$credentials` for example. Please check my answer and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`

> The HTTP authentication method(s) to use. The options are: CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLAUTH_DIGEST, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE, CURLAUTH_NTLM, CURLAUTH_ANY, and CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE.
>
> [PHP Manual / cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

`CURLOPT_USERPWD`

> A username and password formatted as "[username]:[password]" to use for the connection.
>
> [PHP Manual / cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Try updated code to send a POST request to the `/token` endpoint to obtain a token.

You should find a token in the `$result`:

```
$credentials = "$login:$password";
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://demo-accounts.vivapayments.com/connect/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    // Set the auth type as `Basic`
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    // Set login and password for Basic auth
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $credentials,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
    // To send additional parameters in the POST body
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials"
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
// This is the response for your request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// This is the response status code (if you are interested)
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Check out the example and try it out here:
https://paiza.io/projects/e/JQJeAZsOlI5m9OFSda4FQQ

Comment: Now, it's worked! 
I know that here at stackoverflow it is not a good practice to thank, but I can't vote yet  .. so here's a Like (Y)

Comment: @CleberCastiglioni You should be able to mark it as the right answer.